# Select the minimum value from strings starting with a number

Tags: c#, asp.net

An array (`myArray`) with the following values:

```
3 dage¶Voksen¶1680 CZK~
4 dage¶Voksen¶2130 CZK~
5 dage¶Voksen¶2400 CZK~
6 dage¶Voksen¶2640 CZK~
```

I want to select the minimum value on the basis of first digit in the value e.g., 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
i.e., in my case the minimum value is `"3 dage¶Voksen¶1680 CZK"`. However, these number can be any natural number `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...}`. So I want a solution to select the value with the smallest number.

How it would be achieved?

Comment: Where did you stuck in your attempt to solve this?

Comment: what have you attempted?

Comment: You should post something you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: i didn't sort it out myself, that's why i posted it. what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 int small=Convert.ToInt32(MyArray[0].SubString(0,1));
 string result = MyArray[0];
 for(int i=0; i < MyArray.Length; i++)
 {
  if(Convert.ToInt32(MyArray[i].SubString(0,1))<small)
    {
      result=MyArray[i];
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
string []  myArray = new string[]{

    "3 dage¶Voksen¶1680 CZK~",
    "4 dage¶Voksen¶2130 CZK~",
    "5 dage¶Voksen¶2400 CZK~",
    "1 dage¶Voksen¶1680 CZK~",
    "6 dage¶Voksen¶2640 CZK~"
};


var t= myArray.ToList();
t.Sort((a, b) => Convert.ToInt32(a.GetByRegexMatch(@"^\d+"))-Convert.ToInt32(b.GetByRegexMatch(@"^\d+"))) ;
Console.WriteLine (t);
```

result :

[image]

I used this :

```
public static class EXT
{
   public static string GetByRegexMatch(this string st, string RegexPattern)
        {
            Regex txt = new Regex( RegexPattern , RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
            Match m = txt.Match(st);
            return m.Groups[0].Value;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string []  arr = new string[]{

    "3 dage¶Voksen¶1680 CZK~",
    "4 dage¶Voksen¶2130 CZK~",
    "5 dage¶Voksen¶2400 CZK~",
    "1 dage¶Voksen¶1680 CZK~",
    "6 dage¶Voksen¶2640 CZK~"
};
int number;
int min;
min=int.Parse(new string(arr[0].Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()));
for(int i=1;i<arr.Length;i++)
   {
        number = int.Parse(new string(arr[i].Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()));
        if(number<min){
             min = number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is not going to work with `"11113 dage¶Voksen¶1680 CZK~"`

Comment: Yes you are right. Its not the perfect solution but this is how one can approach. In place of taking a digit into consideration one can delimit th e string by spaces or so

Comment: Your solution is correct. I gave him a simpler solution if his integer will always be a single digit.